# How do I verify if $2^{35} \equiv 1 \pmod{71}$ is true or not?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I need to know if $2^{35} \equiv 1\pmod{71}$ is true. I tried using Euler and Fermat little theorem and I got stuck. There is probably something trivial I'm not seeing so I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion)?

Comment: What about "by calculation" (even if you don't know more efficient methods, that would be 35 times multiplying by $2$ modulo $71$, come on...)? I mean, we were lazy students, then, but there were limits.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Especially considering the kind of shortcuts one can take because it is well-known what, say, $2^{10}$ is.

Comment: Further hint: $12^2\equiv 2 \bmod 71$

Comment: On the topic of direct calculation, there are fast exponentiation algorithms such as [Squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Just compute $2^{2^k} \pmod {71}$ for $k \le 5$.

Comment: Use `\pmod{71}` to get $\pmod{71}$

Comment: @ProfessorVector I thought it wouldn't be very time efficient to do that on an exam in case something like this is questioned.

Comment: Then, you should have mentioned "in an exam" *in your question*. But you're right, "time efficient" *does* sound better than "lazy". :P

Comment: I added an easier method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903368/how-do-i-verify-if-235-equiv-1-pmod71-is-true-or-not#comment8051401_3903487).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way:

$$
2^{36}\equiv 64^6 \equiv (-7)^6 \equiv (-343)^2 \equiv 12^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{71} \Rightarrow 2^{35} \equiv 1 \pmod{71}
$$

Comment: $$\large \text{Easier}\!:\  1 \equiv 3^{\large 2} 2^{\large 3} \overset{\!\times\ 2}\Longrightarrow 2 \equiv (3\,2^{\large 2})^{\large 2}\overset{(\ \ )^{\Large 35}\!\!}\Longrightarrow\, 2^{\large 35}\equiv (3\,2^{\large 2})^{\large 70}\equiv 1\ \ \text{by little Fermat}\qquad\qquad$$

Answer (score 3):

$$2^{35} = 2^{10} \times 2^{10} \times 2^{10} \times 2^5 \\
= 1024 \times 1024 \times 1024 \times 32 \\
\equiv 30 \times 30 \times 30 \times 32 \equiv 1 \mod 71.$$

Comment: Should I be using $\equiv$ rather than = here?

Comment: I think the last $=$ should be $\equiv$

Comment: Thanks. Haven't done number theory since my Uni days...

Comment: $=$ should be used only when the number on either side of the symbol are actually equal, because that's what $=$ means. If you're doing any kind of modular reductions, you should use $\equiv$. You could use $\equiv$ everywhere, of course.

Comment: That makes sense, Arthur.

Comment: Why $30 \times 30 \times 30 \times 32 \equiv 1 \mod 71$?

Comment: I thought you might ask that. I did this on my calculator: $30 \times 30 \times 30 \times 32 = 864000\cdot \quad 864000 \div 71 = \text{something}.01408...\cdot \quad 0.01408... \times 71 = 1\cdot \quad $ i.e. the remainder when you divide $864000$ by $71$ is $1 \cdot$

Answer (score 3):

According to [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), $2^{35}\equiv\left(\dfrac2{71}\right)\bmod71$.

Furthermore, $\left(\dfrac2{71}\right)=1$, because $71\equiv-1\bmod8$.

Comment: that's a simple answer ! (+1)

Comment: It works in this specific circumstance

Comment: Oh.. I see... Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Since $71\equiv3$ mod $4$, $k$ is a quadratic residue if and only if $71-k$ is a nonresidue. In particular, $70=71-1$ and $35=71-36$ are nonresidues. But since $70=2\cdot35$, we can conclude that $2$ is a quadratic residue, i.e., $2\equiv a^2$ mod $71$ for some $a$, in which case $2^{35}\equiv a^{70}\equiv1$ mod $71$ by Fermat's little theorem.

Remark: This approach shows that $2$ is the square of something without explicitly finding what it's the square of. In fact, as Keith Bachman points out in comments, $2\equiv12^2$ mod $71$.

Comment: You must have meant $35=7\color{red}1-36$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, yes, thank you. Fixed now.